# compareTo with integer

Tags: java, compareto

I'm trying to use compareTo with an integer but it won't let me. Help please! Here's my code:

```
public int compareTo(Book book)
   {
       if (this.author.compareToIgnoreCase(book.author) < 0) return -1;
       if (this.author.compareToIgnoreCase(book.author) > 0) return 1;
       if (this.author.equalsIgnoreCase(book.author))
       {
           if (this.numOfPages.compareTo(book.numOfPages) < 0) return -1;
           else if (this.lyrics.compareToIgnoreCase(song.lyrics) > 0) return 1;
           else if (this.lyrics == song.lyrics) return 0;
           else return 1;
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: What are the data types of this.numOfPages and book.numOfPages etc?

Comment: If they are small `int`s, you might need to do `new Integer(this.numOfPages).compareTo(book.numOfPages)` maybe?

Comment: Primitives aren't objects so you can't invoke methods on them, just use `==` instead.

Comment: There we go!  Got it to work.  I used a combination of everything and just messed around with it a bit

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are defining numOfPages as :

```
int numOfPages;  //primitive integer
```

if you instead use the object repsentation of `int` , it should work.

for example:

```
Integer numOfPages; //object integer
```

Comment: Or... you know... you could just do `numOfPages < book.numOfPages`

Comment: she is trying to use **compareTo** method, obviously using == is better, but if you insist on using **compareTo** then that's one way of doing it.